# PowerShell $($a) Has Unexpected Result

Tags: powershell

## PowerShell 4 ISE

```
PS> $MyFile = "MyFile.txt"
PS> $a = "dir $MyFile"

PS> $a
> dir MyFile.txt 

PS> $($a)
> dir MyFile.txt
```

Why does `$($a)` not execute the command `"dir MyFile.txt"`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should `$($a)` execute `dir MyFile.txt`?

Comment: you should edit your test and put it as code block

Comment: @PetSerAl my guess is that he's assuming behavior that's more bash-like?

Comment: Executing and evaluating are not the same thing.

Comment: @briantist bash has the `eval` command for that.  I can't think of any language that assumes the contents of a variable are executable code.  Most languages try pretty hard to keep data and executable code separate.

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behavior in powershell. You have to remember *what* you're assigning to `$a` which in this case is a `[String]`.

`$(...)` syntax does execute `...` and return the result, but in this it's "executing" a string literal, just as it would if you had typed it into the command line, *and this is key* **with quotes**.

You might have been thinking it would work more like bash, and it sort of does, but not quite because you can't assign the commands to a variable; they would have to be literally typed in the script:

```
$(dir MyFile.txt)
```

On the other hand, you could do:

```
$(Invoke-Expression $a)
```

But typically you only need the `$()` syntax when you're embedding something complex into a string literal:

```
"I like files named $(dir MyFile.txt)"
```

Comment: @John you're asking why the string is not executed, but what you're really asking is why the _contents of the string_ are not executed. The answer is that PowerShell has no idea it's supposed to. How would it know that `"I am a string"` is not supposed to be executed but `"dir thing"` is? So you must explicitly execute it, which you can do with `Invoke-Expression`.

Answer (score 0):

Script blocks work a little better than character strings for this kind of thing.

Try this:

```
$a = {dir $myfile}
$myfile = "sample.txt"
& $a
```

The ampersand is the call operator, and causes execution.  Executing a script block is more flexible than executing a string.  You can define script blocks that contain more than one command.  That's the idea behind script blocks.  Notice also that the parameter $myfile is not evaluated until run time.